# Скорость загрузки страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, видео, оптимизация-сайтов

Поставил видео в тег `<video>` и при загрузке скорость загрузки страницы значительно падает, а само видео работает "рывками". Какие есть способы это исправить?

Comment: можете отдавать страницу без видео, а видео вгружать через js на виндов лоад, тогда проблема с загрузкой будет меньше бросатся в глаза...

Answer (score 2):

Предпочитайте подход progressive enhancement. Загружайте необходимую функциональность на сайте прежде всего, а потом, отложенно через js, догружайте остальное, обогащающее опыт использования сайта.

В случае с видео, лучший вариант - загрузка видео в js через некоторое время после показа страницы и, когда видео будет полностью загружено - его вывод вместо статичного фона сайта или блока.